# django Thread.start() not working thread.is_alive() returns false

Tags: python, django, multithreading

Like described in the title, my thread isn't working. For more details look at the code below:

**Thread called in callback**

```
def callback(request):
    response_data = {}
    code = request.GET.get('code', None)
    if code:
         response_data['code']= code
         thr = threading.Thread(target=request_token_Api, args=(request, code, response_data))
         thr.setDaemon(True)
         thr.start()
         value =thr.is_alive()
         print("Thread is Alive:",value)
         thr.join()
         return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

The method I'm calling (`request_token_Api`) makes an Oauth2 token request call but when I check with the `thred.is_alive()` I get False in the return when it's supposed to be True and I don't know why. I tried to add `thread.run()` after the `thread.start` but I get in to an `AttributeError` message.

**request_token_Api METHOD**

```
def request_token_Api(request, code, response_data):
    if request.method =='POST':
        url = "https://oauth2.api_token_request.com"
        params = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'client_id': API_KEY,
            'client_secret': SECRET_KEY,
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': URI
        }
        response = requests.get(url, params=params, verify=True)
        reponse= response.json()
        return reponse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `request_token_Api` is exiting before you get a chance to check, and therefore the thread is already done.  In `request_token_Api` you only do something if the method is "POST", but in `callback` you are looking at the `GET` property of the `request` and making sure you have a value there.  So probably those two things will never both be `True`

You should either change the logic of when to call `request_token_Api` or what logic you expect to hold when you're in there.  But if you have a valid `GET` code, you probably did not arrive there with a `POST` method.